# Is it possible to have an https endpoint in a web and worker role in the same cloud service?

Tags: azure, https, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, endpoint

I am trying to expose separate Web API endpoints in both a web role and a worker role in the same cloud service in Azure. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, this is possible. You just have to avoid collisions.

Your web role definition will have a set of endpoints independent from your worker role definition. And... you can have multiple role definitions for both web and worker. You just need to make sure the external port numbers are different.

So... if you have, for example, port 8000 defined for a web role's web api, you'd then need something different (like 8100?) for your worker role's web api. You can't have two role definitions both set up to map the same external port number.

Any load-balancing of that endpoint would be across the instances of that particular role.